# Update a div with a php variable in yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have got a list view of users and the option to rate them by the other users.I want to render partial the update/create rating views in the corresponding divs which is uniquely created with the model id. Here is my code

```
<div id="data.<?php echo $data->a_id; ?>"></div>
<?php

echo CHtml::ajaxButton ("Rate this user",CController::createUrl('/ratings/create',array('id'=>$data->user_id,'type'=>'ajax')),
                              array('update' => '#data.$data->a_id','id'=>uniqid(), 'live'=>'false'));

?>
```

I want to update the data.#a_id which has to be passed from the 'update' option of ajax button. How to achieve that?

The above code produces the following error.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #data.$data->a_id
```

Comment: Try this '#data'.$data->a_id

Comment: Jquery syntax error has gone,but no output.

Comment: check your ajax request is working?

Comment: check your div id. I think its has '.' extra